# About AsyncTask and ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-asynctask

There is a download button on each listview items.When I click the button to downloading things, the button will changed to a progressbar and a asynctask will be executed which will update the progressbar state.

At the same time, I click on the listview items (ListActivity) to a detail page (DetailActivtiy). There's also a progressbar.  What I want is the two bars showing same progress updated by the asynctask. How to make it?

Some code is as follows but it doesn't work well.

```
class DownloadTask{
    ....
    private Button btn = null;
    private ProgressBar pgb = null;
    private AppItem appItem = null;

    public void bind(Button btn, ProgressBar pgb, AppItem appItem)
    {
        this.pgb = pgb;
        this.btn = btn;
        this.appItem = appItem;
        this.pgb.setMax(size);
    }
       ...
}
```

The method "bind" is used when start DetailActivity from ListActivity, so the asynctask will update the progressbar on detail page.But when I go back to the list page, the progresbar on the certain listview item will not be updated, because i don't know where or
when to bind it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a help forum. No one is going to construct the entire thing for you.

Comment: Can you pay if i done this :) stackoverflow is for helping the developers to clarifies the issue what they made. We are not here to write code for you.

Comment: Please visit developer.android.com and refer the topics async tasks and progress dialog.. you will get an idea how to start